# Does Java 8 Jsse provider support sha224withRSA Algorithm?

Tags: java-8

`jdk1.8.0.91` works fine here, but the latest revision (`111`) gives below error:

```
*handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Algorithm constraints check failed: SHA224withRSA*
```

Clients accept the certificate when using `jdk1.8.0.91`, or `jsse.jar` of that distribution. But when I upgrade to the latest revision of Java, I see above error. So which one is the correct behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

This is an update from Java on windows, see below bug link for details
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8064330